# How to crop multiple polygons from raster as fast as possible?

Tags: python, raster, postgresql, rasterio

I am trying to crop raster images using pre-defined geometries (vectors).
I have images from PlanetLabs(daily) and regions of interest. Raster images vary, so they can contain only one area that belongs to only one polygon in the vector dataset, while some rasters can contain multiple (up to 200) polygons. So if I would like to crop these 200 polygons and save them separately, like `1.tiff, 2.tiff, 3.tiff` etc. Currently my function to clip looks like this:

```
analytic_rast = riox.open_rasterio(image_path_analytic)
# here performs processes like  path generation etc
......
#
def mask_out(raster, fields ,out_file_name, gid):
    # filtered by gids
    mask = fields['gid'] == gid
    fields_gwascode = fields.where(mask)
    fields_gwascode = fields_gwascode.dropna()
    raster_clip_fields_gwascode = raster.rio.clip(fields_gwascode['geom'])
    raster_clip_fields_gwascode.rio.to_raster(out_file_name)
analytic_rast.close()
```

Basically, I am calling this function to each raster. I have around 500K regions of interest (polygons) and in addition to the 8 bands raster, I have visual and [UDM](https://developers.planet.com/docs/data/udm-2/) rasters. In total, I have 3 raster images cropped for each polygon. If one set of raster (3 rasters) belongs only to one polygon I am copying (shutil.copy) this tiff file (without opening it).
The function works well, but I am not satisfied with the speed. For cropping multiple polygons the time is really random, sometimes it can finish in 50 seconds for 200 polygons, and sometimes it can take 1200 secs...
I implemented `Pool` with size 19 and each pool process one set of raster. Inside the pool function, I have a loop that iterates over polygons and so on.
The architecture:

```
def crop_poly():

    raster_set = [analytical, visual, udm]
    for raster in raster_set:
       thread_raster = Thread(target=mask_out, args=(raster, poly, acquisition_date,))
       thread_raster.start()

def process_group():
    for poly in polygons:
        crop(poly)
    # i am waiting for threads to be finished
    thread_raster.join()

def main():
    with Pool(19, initializer=initializer) as p:
         p.map(process_group, data)
```

Any suggestion on how can I speed up? My intention is to finish in 5-6 hours or even faster. I am ready to try any new libs or tool.
I have 20 cores and 128 GB RAM.

Comment: Performance tuning is difficult without direct access to your workstation while it's operating. There will be a bottleneck, you need to find it, it could be memory, disc, network... Use task manager and see which is at 100%, most likely network or disc access; you can be at max internet and still not max out your intranet connection.

Comment: @MichaelStimson is the code architecture look okay? In terms of the code, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you performing that on a single server, over the network or accessing the 'to be clipped' raster from the internet? What does task manager look like while you have the script running? You will get the best performance if you have your source raster on an internal drive and store your outputs on a different local drive; the source raster would perform better if you have it on a SSD - you're running 19 processes which means a lot of seek time, this can have the effect of making the script run slower than running one clip at a time. If possible output to a SSD too.

Comment: @MichaelStimson rasters stored on a shared network, so I am reading and writing to the same drive at the same time... Good point. Now I am thinking, to download to the internal drive (for now I have only HDD..), and read it from local and save result to the shared drive. Do you think this idea will help a little? I would like to increase the speed step by step. Furthermore, do you have any libs/frameworks that you can suggest? I am thinking about the dusk, but not sure if that will help me. Furthmore, thinking about rasterizing vectors and masking out them but not sure if that is going to help

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code; the only way I can think of making it any faster is to use C++ but that's not a guarantee of increased performance. A shared network drive suffers not only the network bottleneck but you're also sharing your I/O with other users; if your network drive is a NAS with a RAID you're at the mercy of the parity computation and local caching, if write caching is turned off your NAS may even be slower than a USB external drive. Copying locally might help but if you're processing with a 5400 RPM drive spend some $ and get a SSD (M.2 preferably)

Comment: I wonder, do I understand your code correctly that you are creating 19 processes, and then each process creates ~500.000*3/19 threads... so you have 1.500.000 threads running concurrently?